# How can I use Matlab to dynamically download webpages using sites' search function?

Tags: matlab, url, web

My goal is to download content from search function, using a keyword ("Mexico") from specified websites into strings using the Matlab `urlread` function.

I have for example the following URLs

```
FirstfullURL = ['http://www.economist.com/'];
SecondfullURL = ['http://www.foxnews.com/'];
```

I extract the content:

```
Firststring = urlread(FirstfullURL);
Secondstring = urlread(SecondfullURL);
```

How can I make a search in these websites using my keyword ("Mexico") and then download all the  information relevant to that keyword?

Ideally, I want to indicate to each URL to jump into search function and make the specified reseach.

I tried to use GET option but it wasn't looking through the website search function.

```
Firststring = urlread(FirstfullURL,'Get',{'term','Mexico'});
```

Could you please give me some ideas how to solve this challenge ?

Comment: What do you mean by *download all the relevant information of that keyword*?

Comment: looking for the same answer, did you solved that ? @Karamos

Answer (score 0):

You need an HTML parser or this will get tedious. If you know Java, JSoup works well.

Comment: I am using matlab so I would need a way to reshape the URL to get access into search function. Do you have any recommedations

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to search the word Mexico on the initial page of the economist or do you want to use the search-function of the economist website?

To make it more clear: Do you want the same result as if you hit CTRL+F or do you want to use the search-button on the website?

If you want the latter you need another URL than "economist.com", use in this case

```
http://www.economist.com/search/apachesolr_search/<keyword>
```

in other cases you will have to modify the GET-Params, The LiveHTTP-Headers-Extension for Firefox is fine to find these.

If you want to do the first:

```
 A = urlread('http://theeconomist.com');
 findstr('Economist', A)
```

works totally fine. But I agree with Joshua: Matlab is probably not the best choice to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To make it clear, I want to use the search-button on the website. I have few websites that I would like to make the same search so I am looking for more dynamic way to access the search-button of each website.

Comment: Which programming language is more suitable to get that I want?

Comment: I think a language which has more options to process Text would be a better choice, a HTML parser will make this much easier. on wikipedia you'll find a list of HTML-Parsers, I personally would prefer python with lxml which gives you good options in accessing the content with xPath and RegEX

Comment: Well, if you want to "use" the Search-Button, you'll have to find out what happens when you press that button. Usually a page like example.com/search.php?query=Keyword is called and returns the result-page - so first of all you need to find out what happens if you press that button. Usually that differs a little bit from page to page. To find these URLs and Parameters the Extension mentioned above is a great help